# how to auto click dhtml modal dialog window button using javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

**iframe** having one **dhtml** modal dialog box in that there is one `Button` now i want to automatic click that button using *JavaScript* or *asp.net*

Comment: you dont make an alert box programatically disappear, if thats what you are asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the "dhtml modal dialog box" is a standard browser alert initiated by JavaScript, then you can't programmatically click it using JavaScript.

Your best bet would be to use a custom dialog box.

Related Articles:

- http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/
- http://javascript.about.com/library/blmodald1.htm